# truly lazy cache pattern? F#

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, f#, lazy-evaluation, c#-to-f#

I have the following type for implementing a simple lazy cache:

```
module CachedFoo =

let mutable private lastAccess:Option<DateTime> = None

// returns a lazy value that initializes the cache when
// accessed for the first time (safely)
let private createCacheInitialization() =
    lazy(
        let someObject = SomeLongRunningOperation()
        lastAccess <- Option.Some(DateTime.Now)
        someObject
    )

// current cache represented as lazy value
let mutable private currentCache = createCacheInitialization()

// Reset - cache will be re-initialized next time it is accessed
// (this doesn't actually initialize a cache - just creates a lazy value)
let MaybeReset() =
    if (lastAccess.IsSome && DateTime.Now > (lastAccess.Value + TimeSpan.FromSeconds (10.0))) then
        currentCache <- createCacheInitialization()

let GetCache() =
    MaybeReset()
    currentCache.Value
```

First question: is the above thread-safe? It seems lazy() is thread-safe by default, but I guess I need to put some locking around the assignment of the `lastAccess` field?

Second and most important: this is lazy in the sense that its value is not retrieved until someone demands for it, however, I think I could even do it more lazy by returning the last cached object even in the case that Reset() is called, but launching an async thread in the background that would call this method.

In C# it would be something like this:

```
public SomeObject GetCache() {
    try {
        return currentCache.Value;
    } finally {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(MaybeReset));
    }
}
```

How would I do that in F#? (Bonus points if solution uses fancy async stuff instead of using ThreadPool API).

Comment: What's the rationale for the timeout - it doesn't seem to save on memory given that it only triggers when someone has actually said they want the value? Can the results being cached become stale in some way?

Comment: yes they can, but if I'm able to find a way to code this in F# I will simply reduce the timeout to account for the increase of "staleness" probability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ganesh's insight, I finally went for this solution that doesn't make the 2nd requestor wait on the result while it's being refreshed:

```
module CachedFoo =

let mutable private lastAccess:Option<DateTime> = None

// returns a lazy value that initializes the cache when
// accessed for the first time (safely)
let private createCacheInitialization() =
    lazy(
        let someObject = SomeLongRunningOperation()
        lastAccess <- Option.Some(DateTime.Now)
        someObject
    )

// current cache represented as lazy value
let mutable private currentCache = createCacheInitialization()

let lockObject = new Object()

let timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds (10.0)

// Reset - cache will be re-initialized next time it is accessed
// (this doesn't actually initialize a cache - just creates a lazy value)
let MaybeReset() =
    lock lockObject (fun () ->
        if (lastAccess.IsSome && DateTime.Now > (lastAccess.Value + timeout)) then
            let newCache = createCacheInitialization()
            ignore(newCache.Force())
            currentCache <- newCache
    )

let GetCache() =
    let v = currentCache.Value // to make sure we get the old one
    async { MaybeReset() } |> Async.Start
    v
```

Answer (score 1):

I think updating `lastAccess` is thread-safe for two reasons

- you only do it inside the `lazy` which means that it's only going to be updated once anyway (though there may be a more subtle race with `Reset`, I'm not certain)
- `lastAccess` is a single reference (to `Option`) and so will be updated atomically anyway

To kick off a new "fire and forget" `async` to re-calculate the value, do something like this:

```
let GetCache() =
    let v = currentCache.Value // to make sure we get the old one
    async { MaybeReset() } |> Async.Start
    v
```

Comment: thanks, but I guess you meant to call Reset() and not createCacheInitialization?

Comment: I was copying what your C# did, but then I noticed that just called `createCacheInitialization` without doing anything so I updated my code to write to `currentCache`. You could just call `Reset` of course.

Comment: oh, that was a typo in my C# code! if you don't mind, I'll update your answer, thanks!

Comment: so your solution works actually, but if there's a 2nd requestor that tries to retrieve the value while MaybeReset() is being processed, it will get locked/queued until it finishes, so how could I avoid this by returning the old one as well?

Comment: ok I think I've found a solution, I'm going to upvote yours and put my final solution which includes part of your work, thanks again!